# How can I compute a histogram in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, statistics

I found `Statistics.Sample.Histogram`, but I can't seem to use it. If I want to be able to bin a list into four categories, I expect to be able to do something like this:

```
import Statistics.Sample.Histogram
histogram 4 [1, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 20]
```

But it gives me the error "non type-variable argument in the constraint," which I don't understand at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your dataset is a list, yet the function `histogram` requires something a little bit different. Have you looked at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.14.0.2/docs/Statistics-Sample-Histogram.html?

Comment: Yep, it looks like it needs some `v0` type. But it doesn't say what this is, or how to get data into that format.

Comment: Try creating your vector with `Data.Vector.fromList` and see if that works. Make sure the return type is also well defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`histogram`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.14.0.2/docs/Statistics-Sample-Histogram.html#v:histogram) takes a `Vector` of values, not a list. You can use `Data.Vector`'s [`fromList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:fromList) function to convert your list into a `Vector`:

```
import qualified Statistics.Sample.Histogram as S
import qualified Data.Vector as V

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let xs = V.fromList [1, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 20]
        bins = 4
        (lowerbounds, sizes) = S.histogram bins xs
    print $ V.toList lowerbounds
    print $ V.toList sizes
```

The result is a pair of `Vector`s holding the lower bounds of each interval and the number of samples within each interval - if you want to display them, you'll need to use [`toList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:toList).