# How can I make a histogram from a list of integers in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, statistics, histogram

I'm a Haskell beginner. What's the easiest way of making a histogram from a list of integers? Say I have a list like this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 7, 10]
```

I'd want to be able to `histogram 2 l` (for 2 bins) and have it return:

```
[(0, 3), (1, 5)]
```

Since there are three numbers in the 0th (first) half, and five numbers in the other half.

There are a lot of libraries that seem to do this, but marshalling a list of integers to and from Vectors or other data structures is really confusing me.

Here's one thing I've tried:

```
import Statistics.Sample.Histogram

l =  [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7] :: [Double]

main = print $ snd $ histogram 10 l
```

But the error it throws is:

```
histogram-test.hs:6:8: error:
    • Ambiguous type variables ‘v10’,
                               ‘b0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show (v10 b0))’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘v10’,
                                                          ‘b0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a, b) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance (Show a, Show b, Show c) => Show (a, b, c)
          -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 13 others
        ...plus 19 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: print $ snd $ histogram 10 l
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = print $ snd $ histogram 10 l
  |
6 | main = print $ snd $ histogram 10 l
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

histogram-test.hs:6:22: error:
    • No instance for (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector [] Double)
        arising from a use of ‘histogram’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘histogram 10 l’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘snd $ histogram 10 l’
      In the expression: print $ snd $ histogram 10 l
  |
6 | main = print $ snd $ histogram 10 l
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: And could you please show us your source code for `histogram` ? Thanks.

Comment: @jpmarinier Looks like it’s from the `statistics` package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.15.2.0/docs/Statistics-Sample-Histogram.html

Comment: Did you post this same question 2 years ago? [How can I compute a histogram in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212509/how-can-i-compute-a-histogram-in-haskell)

Comment: OMG I did, wow. I guess this is just a really sticky problem with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to be forcefully explicit with the data types you expect to get.

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 ... 
 λ> 
 λ> import qualified Data.Vector as V
 λ> import Statistics.Sample.Histogram
 λ> 
 λ> l =  [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7] :: [Double]
 λ> hi = (histogram 10 (V.fromList l)) :: (V.Vector Double, V.Vector Int)
 λ> 
 λ> part2 = snd hi
 λ> 
 λ> part2
 [1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,4]
 λ>
```

Also, it could be that the statistics folks are overwhelmingly of the Fortran/C/C++ culture, and consequently they regard Haskell lists as nice stuff for computer scientists; however, when doing *statistics*, lists are expected to be converted into some serious data type, like sequence or vector.

What this error line:

```
No instance for (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector [] Double)
```

means to tell us is that a list cannot make a proper vector, that is a proper food for function `histogram`. You have to allow explicitely the compiler to convert from list to vector.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to implement this yourself without relying on any library (other than containers, to provide a Map type for the result):

```
frequencies :: Ord a => [a] -> M.Map a Int
frequencies = foldr (\x m -> M.insertWith (+) x 1 m) M.empty
```

Comment: This won't group values like a histogram would, though.